# "RuntimeWarning: overflow[...]" in TensorFlow in juypter notebook

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow

I'm implementing a captcha solver in tensorflow (also using ipython/jupyter notebook). After adding more layers to my model it now prints this message in a red box which I don't understand. What does it mean? I'm thinking it has something to do with the loss since I'm using tf.reduce_sum in the loss term (softmax-cross-entropy) which is also mentioned in the message.

```
/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:3: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp
  This is separate from the ipykernel package so we can avoid doing imports until
/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:3: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  This is separate from the ipykernel package so we can avoid doing imports until
/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py:32: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in reduce
  return umr_sum(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
```

What does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

All computers are limited in their numerical precision. Repetitive operations (aka, reduce) can cause scalars to become larger than the maximum value storable for specific type.

One possible option to stop the error is to change the type to reduce precision.